# Javascript manual concat directory hierarchy (like Grunt)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

As a JS novice...  I have a JS app that loads a huge allscripts.js.  This file is produced by Grunt, which collects all the JS files under a multi-level directory hiearchy.  It uses Ulgify too, which makes it difficult to debug.  (FWIW, I also built a JS map file, but it didn't help with debugger single-stepping).

To ease the debugging, I'm trying to simply concat all the source files from all the directories and load the resulting JS.  The idea being that I'll be able to use the debugger to single-step my way to nirvana.

How would I do this?  I have tried a simple:

```
cat app/*/*.js > allscripts.js
```

But it fails to load.  I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

Comment: elaborate "But it fails to load", your code should work fine

Comment: Thanks Udayraj.  Knowing that it really should be as simple as concatenating all my JS files is what I really wanted to be sure of.  FWIW, to deal with mutli-level directories, I had to change my simple `cat` command to be `find app -name '*.js' -exec cat {} > ~/allscripts.js +`, but things still are not right.

Comment: I noticed that compared to rebuilding with Grunt configured with `optimize: "none"`, my manually concatenated file is still much smaller than what Grunt produces, which includes source from external dirs too.  For now, it looks like I'll have to stick with Grunt...